# When is the file removed from the index when you run git rm?

Tags: git

When you delete a file from your project by running the `git rm` command, when is the file actually removed from the index? Is it removed when you commit the deletion or is it removed when `git rm` is run?

From what I understand, a git rm involves the following steps:

1. Remove file from index
2. Remove file from working directory
3. Commit file deletion

I'm just not sure whether the file is removed in the beginning from the index or when the deletion is committed. Also are these steps even correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens immediately, but there is no commit at this point.  That is, only steps 1 and 2 apply.

A good way to think of the index is that it's a *third* copy of everything—or really, a *second* copy, and the work-tree is the third.  That is, at any time, you have:

- A current commit, aka (also known as) `HEAD` or sometimes `@`.  Since this is a commit, it cannot be changed at all.
- A proposed next commit, aka the *index*, aka the *staging area*, aka the *cache*.  (Why three names?  Well, it's Git. :-) )  This is not—not *yet*—a commit, so you can change it.  But it is in a special Git form, where it is really hard to view or work with any of the files stored in it.
- The *work-tree*, which has the files in a form where you (and the rest of your computer) can work with them.  The work-tree can also have *untracked* files in it (and some of those can be ignored as well as untracked)—the index cannot contain untracked files, because by definition, whatever is in the index, is tracked.

Note that you can copy files in both directions here: from `HEAD` to index, from index to work-tree, or from work-tree to index.  But since commits can never be *changed* you can't copy from index back into `HEAD`.  (What you do instead is make a *new* commit—copy from index to new commit.  Of course, that new commit is permanent.)

Comment: If I remove a file from the working directory by using just `rm` and not `git rm`, only the file from the working directory is removed but it still exists in the index, right?

Comment: Right. Git does not complain about this, and the file will be in the next commit you make!

Comment: I should also mention that if you `rm file` (so that it's gone from work-tree but still in `HEAD` and index), then `git add file`, the `git add` step removes the file from the index (!). There are some subtle corner cases that changed behavior between Git 1.x and 2.x here, when you use `git add --all`. It's generally wiser not to get the index and work-tree all mis-matched as to which files are in which ones, as it gets very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git rm` it removes file from the index & working directory.

Reference - [git-rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)